# Is it a good practice to allow a string or an array as argument to a function?

Tags: javascript

Here's an example of what i'm talking about:

With grunt, you have this function:

```
grunt.file.match([options, ] patterns, filepaths)
```

In the doc, they say:

> Both the patterns and filepaths argument can be a single string or array of strings.

So, is it a good practice to allow different types for the same parameter?

[Official doc](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file)

Comment: It's good practice to pass whatever the function expects ?

Comment: Javascript is a bit of a maverick, but yeah I don't see a problem with this. Javascript is loosely typed after all.

Comment: I don't see how a "good practice" question is automatically opinion based. I would hate the entire engineering profession if this were true.

Comment: @adeneo the question pertains to the design of the function: "So, is it a good practice to allow different types for the same parameter?"

Comment: @adeneo anyway, I corrected the question title.

Comment: It can be good practice, depends on the function, if it makes sense to accept both arrays and strings, then there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. In other languages you can *overload* a method with different parameters. In javascript, you do not have this luxury, but what we do have is weak-type declarations. So javascript does not care what you pass, it is your job to make sure that your function accepts all possible arguments.

**Edit**
As @jwatts1980 suggested, your function should be flexible enough to *handle* any potential arguments. If you have a parameter called `name`, you should expect it to occasionally be `null`, and chance might have it that you receive an array of `names`, in which case you might choose to iterate over the `names` (`name`) and do whatever you would do with one `name`.

Comment: My semantic argument is that is not a JS programmers job to make sure a function "accepts" all possible arguments, but rather "handles" all possible arguments. If the function is specifically expecting a string and an array of strings is passed, it should either throw an meaningful error, ignore it / return useful value (such as null, or an empty value) depending on the case, or go ahead and process it. In other words, do something other than fail out unexpectedly.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I wouldn't argue it's "accepting" all possible arguments. But, in a condition where you might allow a string, or array of strings, or a boolean or string, or int or string int, it's perfectly acceptable. It could be considered similar to passing an "object value" in c#, for example, and parsing it to what you need. And if it fails, you would throw an error, as would be expected.

Comment: My dictionary definition of "accept" is "consent to receive (a thing offered)", I'm pretty sure that is the word I am looking for (in the context of the OP's question) but I made a note in my answer expounding on what it should do with the "handled" arguments.

Comment: BTW, I upvoted your answer prior to my comment. I knew what you "meant", but I thought the semantic argument may be important in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: Ah sweet. I appreciate that. I do see how confusion could arise from the wording. Thanks @jwatts1980.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to be agnostic between a single piece of data and a collection of data. This lets functionally-oriented code flow very well since it is trivial to "promote" a singleton to an array. The functional people (e.g. Haskell programmers) will be able to explain this more fully, but from my experience as a programmer I will definitely answer "yse" in the meantime.

Comment: I'm going to be skeptical of these downvotes until I hear an explanation otherwise.

Comment: That's not at all a general case. E.g a string can be iterated over with for… in so a function that takes a string or an Array might have to have extra logic, which may or may not be worth it.

Comment: @Touffy Firstly of course the function will have extra logic, the goal is to to make it easier for the *caller*, not the implementor. This is true in all modern programming and software engineering. Secondly of course it's not a general case: my answer details the specific case in which this is good practice. It's not good practice in general but I don't think I need to go into that.

Comment: (I know, don't use for… in on an Array. You get my point. You'd have to check if the value you get should be considered as a single value or not, and it may be tricky to cover all cases)

Comment: That's neither good practice nor common practice.

Comment: @Nit of course it's common practice, see e.g. the example in the original question (ftr grunt is *really* widely used). I explained why it's good practice, would you mind explaining why it's not if you think so?

Comment: @djechlin It's common only in libraries; libraries are by far a minority of the code worldwide.

Comment: @Nit right click this page, click "Inspect element", then "sources" and tell me how many libraries you see or don't see. But I'm not debating this since no software engineer would make that claim and I don't have time to explain the whole profession today.

Comment: It's actually a fairly common practice when working with jQuery plugins. Granted, that could be what Nit is referring to when he says "libraries". But, as KJ Price points out in his answer, other languages allow overrides. In JS you would need additional logic to check the type on how to handle the argument, and though that's additional overhead, it's not uncommon.

Comment: @djechlin You make more logical fallacies in a single comment than anyone should be bothered to count. https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/assets/FallaciesPosterHigherRes.jpg

Answer (score 1):

For some functions it's natural to assume input could come in more than one form and allowing for it can often result in more elegant APIs.

In the case of single value vs array, there are a number of reasons that you might want to convert the parameter into an array.

### It can help your code be more expressive

This is especially true when you are writing a functions that deal with data transforms. If you support both values and lists, then you can manipulate it in a unified way through the main part of the function body.

```
// triple everything passed to it
math.triple = function(xs) {
  if(!(xs instanceof Array)) {
    xs = [xs];
  }

  var txs = xs.map(function(x) {
    return x * 3;
  });

  return txs.length > 1 ? txs : txs[0];
};
```

Dealing with data in this unified way is a pretty powerful concept. You don't have to worry about two code paths (one for each input type) or writing entirely new functions (overloading).

The user won't have to worry about remembering to wrap their input into an array.

```
math.triple(3);        // 9
math.triple([1, 2, 3]); // [3, 6, 6]
```

### It makes functional programming easier

In this case, the differentiation is between a function and a value, rather than a list and a value.

```
function map(array, value) {
   var fn = value,
       transformed = [];

   if(typeof value !== 'function') {
     fn = function() { return value };
   }

   array.forEach(function(item) {
     transformed.push(fn(item));
   });

   return transformed;
 }
```

We can implement `map` in terms of `forEach` and the new map function will either take a value or a function.

```
 // old map
 [1, 2, 3].map(function() { return 0; });  // [ 0, 0, 0 ]
 // old map
 [1, 2, 3].map(0);                         // TypeError: 0 is not a function

 // new map
 map([1, 2, 3], 0);                        // [ 0, 0, 0 ]
 // new map
 map([1, 2, 3], function() { return 0; }); // [ 0, 0, 0 ]
```

The new version of map is more robust as it supports both types of transforms and can save the user some time both mentally, remembering function names and physically, because the syntax is lighter.

### Know when it's appropriate

It's a bad idea to try and make every function you write support a multitude of different options. You'll never be able to remember them all, writing tests will be a pain and it will confuse the people that have to use them. You'll inadvertently introduce a lot of bugs, because it can be hard for your brain to figure out what exactly a function will do with a given set of arguments.

There are some occasions where it is appropriate to assimilate parameters, but it's not that often and when you decide that it is appropriate, then you are also signing up to writing clear documentation that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to **document what your function does** and explain its heuristics if it uses any. A function that accepts different kinds of input can be very intuitive to call, or it can cause unexpected behavior. Especially in the case of String vs Array since they have similar behavior to some extent (both have integer-indexed properties and a *length*), and someone might reasonably want to treat the string as an array of characters in some cases, and as a single value in others.

Comment: It is good practice to document what a function does, but the pith of the design question is not whether to accept wildly different types, but whether to accept a singleton or collection, so your answer is a bit irrelevant. Without looking at the library function in question I can nearly guarantee it would *not* be reasonable to treat a string as a char array here.

Comment: I think it's very relevant to consider whether a string is a collection or a singleton, in a question that asks specifically about those two types. Just because a use case is unlikely doesn't mean you can safely prevent it. It's easier to wrap a string in `[]` than to work around a function that "knows what's good for you".